# How to fix: The value cannot be null or empty. (Parameter 'mediaType')

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, dropbox-sdk

In my .NET 7 (7.0.5) project I'm using the Dropbox Sign SDK (latest version 1.1.1).

When I call the `SignatureRequestSendAsync` (see code below) I receive the following error:

`System.ArgumentException: The value cannot be null or empty. (Parameter 'mediaType')`

```
var signingApi = new SignatureRequestApi(
    new Dropbox.Sign.Client.Configuration {
        Username = _configuration["DropboxSign:Key"]
    }
);

var newSigningRequest = new SignatureRequestSendRequest
{
    Title = "Document to sign",
    Message = "Please sign this document",
    Signers = listOfSigners,
    Files = listOfFiles,
    [...]
}

var signingResponse = await signingApi.SignatureRequestSendAsync(newSigningRequest);
```

As far as I can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75400881/the-value-cannot-be-null-or-empty-parameter-mediatype) and [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1969), this is due to a null reference conflict between .NET 7 and RestSharp prior to version 109. The Dropbox SDK reference RestSharp version 108.0.1.

Is there anything I can do myself to fix this until the error is fixed by the Dropbox team? I've tried downloading a newer version of RestSharp to my project, but that breaks the Dropbox SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the NET team actually [addressed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/83425/files) the issue with `null` values being passed — it defaults them to `text/plain`, the way NET 6.0 used to handle them.

I'm running a test project on NET 7.0.7 with Dropbox Sign's RestSharp 108.0.1 dependency and have had no issues.

Comment: Yes, the .NET 7.0.8 update fixed it. :)